# Bash directory variable error

Tags: bash, variables

In a bash script I get to this point

```
read ENE CX CY CZ <<< $(head -n 1 RESULTS_${lach}tal2)
echo $ENE
SED_ARG="-e 's/-/m/g'"
read CX2 <<< $( echo ${CX} | eval sed "$SED_ARG")
read CY2 <<< $( echo ${CY} | eval sed "$SED_ARG")
read CZ2 <<< $( echo ${CZ} | eval sed "$SED_ARG")
DIREC="${CX2}_${CY2}_${CZ2}"
echo $DIREC
cd "$DIREC"
```

the value of variable DIREC is the name of a directory and I get things like

```
m25.1240_m22.1250_m5.1540
```

this directory does exist, and if I do directly in bash `cd m25.1240_m22.1250_m5.1540` it works and I can get inside. But on the script it does not work and I get the error:

```
: No such file or directory: cd: m25.1240_m22.1250_m5.1540
```

I do not understand why the error

PS:

```
echo "$DIREC" | od -c
```

gives

```
0000000   m   2   5   .   1   2   4   0   _   m   2   2   .   1   2   5
0000020   0   _   m   5   .   1   5   4   0  \r  \n
0000033
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `$DIREC` has some whitespace that shouldn't be there. Try `cd $DIREC` (without the quotes) and see what happens.

Comment: is this path in the same folder the script is called from?

Comment: How do you invoke the script? Do a `pwd` inside the script to see if its current directory is the one you expect.

Comment: if I do pwd inside the script, I am exactly there, and of course the script is also at pwd

Comment: Does your `RESULTS_${lach}tal2` file have windows-style line endings? Does `CZ` end with a carriage return? What does this show: `echo "$DIREC" | od -c`

Comment: no, all files are generated in linux

Comment: how could i remove anyway the carriage return?? it seems to be there, trying your trick

Comment: ok that was the thing, I removed it with cat filea | tr -d "\r" > fileb

Comment: glenn, how can i give yo uthe points for the answer?

Comment: If you want to, I provided an answer of my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your `RESULTS_${lach}tal2` file have windows-style line endings? Does `CZ` end with a carriage return? What does this show:

```
echo "$DIREC" | od -c
```

---

Additionally, there's a lot of unnecessary eval'ing going on. Bash can do replacements in variable substitution:

```
read ENE CX CY CZ <<< $(head -n 1 RESULTS_${lach}tal2 | sed 's/\r$//')
DIREC="${CX/-/m}_${CY/-/m}_${CZ/-/m}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that inside the script, your working directory is elsewhere, thus you cannot cd. Try this: instead of

```
cd "$DIREC"
```

replace it with

```
echo current directory is $PWD
cd "m25.1240_m22.1250_m5.1540"
```

and see if you still have the same problem.

Comment: yes, I checked that I am in that directory and the script too. and cd "m25..." works of course, but I need to do it for a general case